# Facebook Audience Network not showing real ads without mediation but test Ads are showing

Tags: android, facebook, networking, audience

I try to use Facebook Audience Network on my android app without mediation but it is not showing real ads and test Ads are showing.

Any idea? I'm so stuck with it.

browser_activity.java

```
  AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(this);

  adView = new AdView(this, "718544759324520_718567389322257",AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);

  LinearLayout adContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adViewFAN);

  adContainer.addView(adView);

  adView.loadAd();
```

activity_browser.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/adViewFAN"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/swapToRefresh"
    app:adUnitId="@string/ad_banner_id"
    />
```

image SS
[No mediation platform (Audience Network only)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPA0f.png)

Comment: same issue, any luck?